# Plotting kmeans cluster in R - how to reproduce fviz_clust with ggplot

Tags: r

I have run a kmeans clustering on 21 observations of four variables. I get a nice plot when I use the following code:

```
fviz_cluster(kmeans_sag, pcScores_sag[, -5], ellipse.type = "norm")
```

But I need to extract the coordinates of each data point because I need to do additional manipulation in ggplot. For example, I need to change the shape of the points, manually set the color, and set the color of the geom_polygons. How can I extract the coordinates plotted by fviz_clust?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object produced by `fviz_cluster` is already a ggplot object. You can adjust the mapping and theme yourself, but if you want to start off with just the data, you can extract it from the ggplot object produced by the function.

We don't have your data, but using the example from the docs, we can do:

```r
library(factoextra)

set.seed(123)

km.res <- kmeans(scale(iris[, -5]), 3, nstart = 10)

clust_plot <- fviz_cluster(km.res, iris[, -5], ellipse.type = "norm")
```

We can get the co-ordinates and cluster labels like this:

```r
df <- clust_plot$data
```

Now we have a data frame that looks like this:

```r
head(df)
#>   name         x          y    coord cluster
#> 1    1 -2.257141 -0.4784238 5.323576       1
#> 2    2 -2.074013  0.6718827 4.752956       1
#> 3    3 -2.356335  0.3407664 5.668437       1
#> 4    4 -2.291707  0.5953999 5.606421       1
#> 5    5 -2.381863 -0.6446757 6.088877       1
#> 6    6 -2.068701 -1.4842053 6.482388       1
```

And can generate our own vanilla ggplot like this:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, shape = cluster, color = cluster)) +
  geom_point(size = 5)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-08-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The documentations for `fviz_cluster`, `ggscatter` (underlying scatterplot function) and `ggpar` lists a number of parameters you can tune, including shape, -size, colors. Since the chart is `ggplot`, you can also add custom `scale`s and `theme`s.

Example:

```
library(factoextra)

iris.scaled <- scale(iris[, -5])
km.res <- kmeans(iris.scaled, 3, nstart = 10)

p <-
fviz_cluster(km.res, iris[, -5],
             shape = 1, ## see ?ggscatter for arguments
             pointsize = 10, ## see ?fviz_cluster for arguments
             ellipse.type = "norm"
             ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('1' = 'yellow', '2' = 'brown', '3' = 'black')) +
  theme_bw()

p
```

[image: psychedelic clusterplot]

If you want the data nonetheless, you can retrieve them with `p$data` (*credits to Allan Cameron*).

Comment: You can get the data with `p$data` - no need to build first.